# Cannot see tables when linking to AZURE SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, lightswitch-2013

I am attempting to link to tables in an AZURE SQL database via ODBC that I created using Visual Studio 2013 Lightswitch.  I am able to attach to the database using SQL Server Native Client 10.0 and see all of the tables EXCEPT for the tables/entities I created with VS 2013 Lightswitch and published to Azure.  I am trying to link the tables in Microsoft Access via ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

I created the ODBC connector within Access rather than the ODBCAD32.exe in the Windows Control Panel and the tables/entities that were previously not present did appear. Not sure why.